# Zeppelin anaconda: current user does not have write permissions

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm using zeppelin on k8s and it's working fine.

I'm trying to install a new dependency using conda interpreter `%python.conda`.

I'm able to list packages:

[image]

The problem arises when I'm trying to install a new package:

[image]

I've also tried to interact with shell and perform `conda` commands directly:

```
➜ kubectl exec -ti python-eubsrx -- sh
$ conda install tensorflow
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /opt/conda/pkgs/cache/9e0f62c3.json
  uid: 1000
  gid: 0

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1000:0 /opt/conda/pkgs/cache/9e0f62c3.json

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

Comment: please file Jira at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN

Comment: I solved it running interpreter pod as `root`...

Comment: anyway, please file Jira, so it will be solved "correctly"